# Another and probably not last question about Radeon and Intel graphics

Tags: graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

So I decided to try to do sth with my graphics on Ubuntu MATE 16.04 but unfortunately it is so confusing what to do and what to use that i have just lost inside all these forum threads.
Below is my configuration and some `dmesg` output:

```
$ lspci -k | grep VGA -A2
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars XTX [Radeon HD 8790M]
    Subsystem: Dell Mars XTX [Radeon HD 8790M]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

`dmesg`:

```
$ dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon'
[    0.722993] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    0.744504] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[    0.747920] radeon 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    0.748074] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (OLAND 0x1002:0x6606 0x1028:0x05BE).
[    0.748085] [drm] register mmio base: 0xF7C00000
[    0.748085] [drm] register mmio size: 262144
[    0.769832] [drm] GPU not posted. posting now...
[    0.773174] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 2048M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000007FFFFFFF (2048M used)
[    0.773175] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GTT: 2048M 0x0000000080000000 - 0x00000000FFFFFFFF
[    0.773176] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=2048M, BAR=256M
[    0.773177] [drm] RAM width 128bits DDR
[    0.773375] [drm] radeon: 2048M of VRAM memory ready
[    0.773376] [drm] radeon: 2048M of GTT memory ready.
[    0.773382] [drm] Loading oland Microcode
[    0.773448] [drm] Internal thermal controller without fan control
[    0.773492] [drm] probing gen 2 caps for device 8086:c01 = 261ad03/e
[    0.779738] [drm] radeon: dpm initialized
[    0.781259] [drm] Found VCE firmware/feedback version 50.0.1 / 17!
[    0.781264] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 524288, num gpu pages 524288
[    0.781997] [drm] probing gen 2 caps for device 8086:c01 = 261ad03/e
[    0.782000] [drm] PCIE gen 3 link speeds already enabled
[    0.784027] [drm] PCIE GART of 2048M enabled (table at 0x00000000002E8000).
[    0.784118] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[    0.784120] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff880414defc00
[    0.784121] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c04 and cpu addr 0xffff880414defc04
[    0.784122] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c08 and cpu addr 0xffff880414defc08
[    0.784123] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff880414defc0c
[    0.784124] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c10 and cpu addr 0xffff880414defc10
[    0.784539] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000075a18 and cpu addr 0xffffc90002835a18
[    0.885095] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VCE init error (-110).
[    0.885103] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    0.885105] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    0.885106] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: MSI limited to 32-bit
[    0.885138] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: using MSI.
[    0.885167] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[    1.060590] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs
[    1.060594] [drm] ring test on 1 succeeded in 1 usecs
[    1.060598] [drm] ring test on 2 succeeded in 1 usecs
[    1.060605] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 4 usecs
[    1.060610] [drm] ring test on 4 succeeded in 3 usecs
[    1.236599] [drm] ring test on 5 succeeded in 1 usecs
[    1.236604] [drm] UVD initialized successfully.
[    1.236827] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    1.236853] [drm] ib test on ring 1 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    1.236877] [drm] ib test on ring 2 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    1.236903] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    1.236927] [drm] ib test on ring 4 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    1.884828] [drm] ib test on ring 5 succeeded
[    1.885756] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[    1.885759] [drm] Connector 0:
[    1.885760] [drm]   VGA-1
[    1.885762] [drm]   DDC: 0x65c0 0x65c0 0x65c4 0x65c4 0x65c8 0x65c8 0x65cc 0x65cc
[    1.885763] [drm]   Encoders:
[    1.885764] [drm]     CRT1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_DAC1
[    1.973127] radeon 0000:01:00.0: No connectors reported connected with modes
[    1.973131] [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes - going 1024x768
[    1.973697] [drm] fb mappable at 0xE06EA000
[    1.973698] [drm] vram apper at 0xE0000000
[    1.973699] [drm] size 3145728
[    1.973700] [drm] fb depth is 24
[    1.973700] [drm]    pitch is 4096
[    1.973848] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fb1: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
[    1.985929] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.43.0 20080528 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
[    1.986416] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M
[    1.986422] fb: switching to inteldrmfb from VESA VGA
[    1.986560] [drm] Replacing VGA console driver
[    1.994908] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    1.994910] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    2.070687] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20151010 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 1
[    2.360875] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    2.360956] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[   12.086398] [drm] probing gen 2 caps for device 8086:c01 = 261ad03/e
[   12.086402] [drm] PCIE gen 3 link speeds already enabled
[   12.089755] [drm] PCIE GART of 2048M enabled (table at 0x00000000002E8000).
[   12.089842] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[   12.089844] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff880414defc00
[   12.089845] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c04 and cpu addr 0xffff880414defc04
[   12.089846] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c08 and cpu addr 0xffff880414defc08
[   12.089848] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff880414defc0c
[   12.089848] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c10 and cpu addr 0xffff880414defc10
[   12.090257] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000075a18 and cpu addr 0xffffc90002835a18
[   12.190805] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VCE init error (-110).
[   12.532308] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs
[   12.532313] [drm] ring test on 1 succeeded in 1 usecs
[   12.532316] [drm] ring test on 2 succeeded in 1 usecs
[   12.532322] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 3 usecs
[   12.532327] [drm] ring test on 4 succeeded in 3 usecs
[   12.708292] [drm] ring test on 5 succeeded in 2 usecs
[   12.708298] [drm] UVD initialized successfully.
[   12.708325] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   12.708349] [drm] ib test on ring 1 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   12.708372] [drm] ib test on ring 2 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   12.708394] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   12.708417] [drm] ib test on ring 4 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   22.860229] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 5 stalled for more than 10000msec
[   22.860233] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000002 last fence id 0x0000000000000004 on ring 5)
[   22.860320] [drm:uvd_v1_0_ib_test [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: fence wait failed (-35).
[   22.860340] [drm:radeon_ib_ring_tests [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: failed testing IB on ring 5 (-35).
```

And i don't know what should i do to make it work even only on Radeon hardware without any power saving. I know that somewhere here are people who has much more experience with graphics hardware than i have :)

Some more information:

```
$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 3
Provider 0: id: 0x6e cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 8 associated providers: 2 name:Intel
Provider 1: id: 0x42 cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 2 outputs: 1 associated providers: 2 name:OLAND @ pci:0000:01:00.0
Provider 2: id: 0x42 cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 2 outputs: 1 associated providers: 2 name:OLAND @ pci:0000:01:00.0
```